# How to Store Lists into a List in STL

Tags: c++, list, stl, arraylist

I would like to generate lists of some numbers between 1 to n
suppose initially lists are:

```
   L1: 1
   L2: 2
   L3: 3
   L5: 4
       .
       .
   Ln-1: n-1
   Ln: n
```

There are total n lists containing 1 to n initially .
Now i would like to update the lists.

Please tell me how to create lists like this in C++ using STL list.

I am trying like this.

```
list<int> first[n+1];
```

And then storing :

```
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
     first[i].push_back(i);
```

But i am getting runtime error,

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

```
list<int> a = {1,2,3};
 list<int> b = {4,5};
 list<int> c = {5,6};
```

can we do:

```
    list<int>a[3];
 then 
    a[0].push_back(1);
    a[0].push_back(2);       
    a[0].push_back(3);
    a[1].push_back(4);
    a[1].push_back(5);
    a[2].push_back(5);
    a[2].push_back(6);
```

Comment: another alternative is to use `std::vector<std::list<int>>` if `n` is not known up front.

Comment: @Grigoriy Chudnov can you please explain more?

Comment: See the billz answer. He creates a vector of lists. Actually I'm not sure what is problem, do I don't know what to recommend.

Comment: @UpendraJat Why don't you add the exact code that causes your runtime problem, and a copy of the run time error message you get, and we take it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjacency List

```
vector< vector<int> > Vec (n+1);
```

It can full fill the requirement.